# How to hide the whole Desktop with a permanent fullscreen image (above)?

Tags: boot, grub2, desktop-environments, .desktop, fullscreen

I use Ubuntu to make a kinda hotSpot (wifi).

**I dont want anyone (thief or hacker) to be able to navigate into the system by pluggin-in keyboard-mouse-screen.** (Unless me or my collaborators). At boot my system is not running `root`, but just a standard user.

I think about using Ubuntu server distro, but I really need Desktop. However it would be great to see only a fullscreen image, above the desktop, displayed from boot. Entering desktop mode (or disabling the image layer) could be done by making a secret key combination, for instance, or by clicking a corner of the image...

My question is: Is there a way, from an Ubuntu desktop distribution,to avoid landing on the desktop by displaying a fullscreen icon instead ?

Thank you --

Comment: All can be done, but: silly question, but locking the screen is no (sufficient) option?

Comment: This is... right.

Comment: Do you mean it *is* sufficient, or it isn't ? :)

Comment: Sufficient I guess. Yes it is. But locked screen asking for password ?

Comment: If your account is set to access with password, yes. *If* it is sufficient, would you mind if I posted it as an answer? I would be happy to help you from the zero- accepted record :) (so far, you haven't been very lucky on AU :) )

Comment: ;) you should post an answer.

Comment: Great that it works , done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a system is really completely unattended, preventing a hacker from accessing your system is practically impossible (only think of simply restarting the system from an external medium).

Having said that, what you describe can be done with a background script, but it already exists in the form of... Lockscreen :)

Simply Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, and click the lock symbol.

[image]

The solution assumes you set a password to your account (can be done with a "normal" user account).

Comment: Actually, my FS is LUKS-encrypted ;) And keyfile is on a USB pendrive.  I want to prevent from the case I leave the USB pluggedin while I'm on the toilet ;) BUT the more important, I d like to have a lockscreen at Launch, no manual thing to do.